# What to do with unmerged files?

Tags: git

When I check a status of a file (with `git status file_name.py`) I get the following message:

```
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)
```

So, I try to use `git commit`. As a result I get the following error:

```
error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
```

And I have names of two files with letter `U` in front of them. When I check their status with `git status file2.py` I get the following:

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

    deleted by them: path/to/my/file2.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Now I am not sure what is wrong with these files and what should I do with them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As message says the other branch with which you're merging deleted the file, you've inserted some modifications to it.

Now either you should confirm file removal by `git rm <path>` or your changes by `git add <path>` and then continue with your commit.